# How to access microphone in worklight 6.0.0.2?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, pocketsphinx-android

I am currently developing a mobile app that converts voice to text using pocketsphinx imported in worklight. Its working fine in mozilla alone but the microphone is not getting recognised in any of the other browsers or in the worklight. So how to get away with this??

Answer (score 0):

[Google's documentation for capturing audio](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) states that you must add the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml. You do not state whether you've done so or not, nor do you provide any errors you see in LogCat, nor anything else to work with.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Verify you've added the above permissions.
Edit the questions with error logs.
Provide demo Worklight project exhibiting your problem.